# Rock, Paper, Scissors Game in Python

Tags: python

I've coded a rock, paper, scissors game in Python and everything works when I run it, but it will only run if I use:

```
def play_game(player1, player2, beats):

    if (player1 == player2):
        return ("Tie")
    elif (player1 == beats[player2]):
        return ("Player 1 wins.")
    elif (player2 == beats[player1]):
        return ("Player 2 wins.")

    beats = {
        'scissors': 'rock',
        'rock': 'paper',
        'paper': 'scissors',
         }


    player1 = input("Please enter either rock, paper, or scissors: ")
        while player1 not in beats.keys():
        player1 = input("That isn't an option. Please try again.")

    player2 = input("Please enter either rock, paper, or scissors: ")
        while player2 not in beats.keys():
        player2 = input("That isn't an option. Please try again.")

    if (player1 == player2):
        print("tie")

    elif(player1 == beats[player2]):
        print("Player 1 wins")

    elif(player2 == beats[player1]):
        print("Player 2 wins")
```

I have two sections explaining player wins etc. but if I delete the def play_game it still works but it I delete the 'if' with the 'elif' at the bottom it no longer prints whats under the def play_game portion.

Comment: It wouldn't allow me to post so I made everything intended, but the only thing that I have intended is: (except def play_game) def play_game(player1, player2, beats):

    if (player1 == player2):
        return ("Tie")
    elif (player1 == beats[player2]):
        return ("Player 1 wins.")
    elif (player2 == beats[player1]):
        return ("Player 2 wins.")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you delete the function play_game() that you never call and aren't using, nothing happens ... and if you delete the lines at the bottom of the file which print who wins then it stops printing who wins?

If you want to use the function play_game, you have to call it. Replace the `if/elif/elif` bits with a call to `play_game(..)`

```
def play_game(player1, player2, beats):

    if (player1 == player2):
        return ("Tie")
    elif (player1 == beats[player2]):
        return ("Player 1 wins.")
    elif (player2 == beats[player1]):
        return ("Player 2 wins.")

beats = {
    'scissors': 'rock',
    'rock': 'paper',
    'paper': 'scissors',
 }


player1 = input("Please enter either rock, paper, or scissors: ")
while player1 not in beats.keys():
    player1 = input("That isn't an option. Please try again.")

player2 = input("Please enter either rock, paper, or scissors: ")
while player2 not in beats.keys():
    player2 = input("That isn't an option. Please try again.")

message = play_game(player1, player2, beats)
print message
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't catch that.